# How can AngularJS be used replace .asp includes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, url-routing

Building a small framework for `.aspx` sites. Project is called [Dwarf](https://github.com/JGallardo/dwarf) and available on GitHub.

The problem that I am addressing is working with partials. For example in one of my pages I have a section in the side bar that pulls in an `.html` file. The reference in the page is

```
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/product-pages/product-links-contact-rep.html" -->
```

How can I integrate AngularJS to use partials here?

I am thinking

```
<!-- this is just an example -->
<script type=text/ng-template id=product-links-contact-rep.html>
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul>
      <li><ahref="http://www.example.com/link1">link 1</a></li>
      <li><ahref="http://www.example.com/link2">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

And that entire script goes in the page?, and how would the routing be addressed for a partial?

I am from a rails background and novice to ASP and new to Angular. So I would appreciate being pointed out where the gaps in my knowledge are so that I can do further research on my own.

Comment: there are numerous ways to use include templates in angular....you likely need to get a deeper understanding of how angular works before determining approach you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you can start with (not saying its the best one) but meets your need is to use directives in angularjs

Here's the code

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


});
app.directive("sidebar",function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: "product-links-contact-rep.html.html",
    link : function(scope,element,attr) {
       // Do Great things here with your sidebar
    },
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Side Bar</title>  

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="product-links-contact-rep.html.html">
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/link1">link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/link2">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div sidebar></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the working plunker code for reference : http://plnkr.co/edit/NAR1g5?p=preview

Comment: Should not the `ng-app` be added to the `<html>` tag though? like `<html ng-app="ngAppDemo">` as discussed at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

Comment: It completely depends on you, whether you need a single app for your project or a project with multiple apps. You can assign ng-app to div also.